# Can someone explain this code snippet in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_replace(array('#/(.?)#e', '/(^|_|-)+(.)/e'), 
            array("'::'.strtoupper('\\1')", "strtoupper('\\2')"), $text);
```

I've never used regex this way,how does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it even work?

```
echo camelize('http://google.com/');
```

Result:

```
Http:::/google.com::
```

Most of how it "works" can be found on the documentation for [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). It uses the array form to make multiple replacements (see example 2). It uses the `e` switch to execute PHP code instead of making a string replacement.

Answer (score 2):

usually its: `preg_replace('/pattern/flags', $replacement, $text)`.

here first and second arguments are array of the same size, it's like you call preg_replace for each $element of the arrays.

secondly, `/` is usually the pattern delimiter but in fact you can use any character, just use it as the first and its the delimiter. (here `#` is used in the first pattern)

in the replacement string, `\\1` (which is `\1` escaped) means the content of the first *parenthesis* matched and `\2` is the second match.

in this case `\1` is what is match by `.?` in the first pattern and `\2` is what `.\ matched in the second pattern

Answer (score 1):

Replace what is matched by `/(.?)` with `'::'.strtoupper('\\1')` where `\1` is replaced by what is matched in regex group 1: `(.?)`

And replace what is matched by `(^|_|-)+(.)` with `strtoupper('\\2')` where `\2` is replaced by what is matched in regex group 2: `(.)`

regex #1: `/(.?)` means:

```
/       # match the character '/'
(       # start capture group 1
  .?    #   match any character except line breaks and match it once or none at all
)       # end capture group 1
```

and regex #2: `(^|_|-)+(.)` means:

```
(      # start capture group 1
  ^    #   match the beginning of the input
  |    #   OR
  _    #   match the character '_'
  |    #   OR
  -    #   match the character '-'
)+     # end capture group 1 and repeat it one or more times
(      # start capture group 2
  .    #   match any character except line breaks
)      # end capture group 2
```

Note that `^` matches the start of the input, *not* the literal `^`!